# I can't get my code to run through and IDE but I can through IDLE (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

So I'm still super new to coding and I was trying to setup some automation. Since I'm still new to it I was just going to have my mouse to the icons and stuff and click when it gets to it's location and I was gonna make it better over time. Anyway whenever I run it via double click or Sublime it won't run however it will run through IDLE. It will print the first few things but doesn't do anything after I enter an input. It does just fine through IDLE. Both Sublime and IDLE don't say any errors.

```
import keyboard

res = pyautogui.size()

point = pyautogui.position()

print('Your screen resolution is ' + str(res))

print('Mouse Location is ' + str(point))

auto = input('Please enter automation command:')

if auto == 'Gmail':
    pyautogui.moveTo(661, 1079, duration=.1)

else:
    print('Currently Not Supported')
```

Comment: You might not have set up your IDE properly. For sublime you can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-sublime-text-3-for-python-in-windows/) and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is a text editor, and needs to be set up properly.

Try this: open Command Prompt then navigate to the folder where your script is.

- type `python script_name.py` and see if it runs.
- if it runs, then your python installation is ok, you just need to set up Sublime. check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFciV6Ew5r4